# What's the name for a polygon with exactly two sets of side lengths?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a name for the shape similar to a regular polygon, but using exactly $2$ side lengths (or $n$ side lengths) instead of one side length?

Comment: I've not heard of a term, but for two side lengths at regular angles I'd guess "truncated polygon" as there is a closely related term "truncated polyhedron".

Comment: Would "truncated regular polygon" be more specific, or does a truncated polyhedron normally refer to a regular polyhedron by default?

Comment: Yea I didn't know Wikipedia mentions it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_polyhedron#Truncation_of_polygons.